# jquery animate width/height doesnt work with variable value

Tags: jquery

```
selfanimate.animate(
          {
            width: '250px',
            height: '250px',
          },
          500
        );
```

If I try to animate this element using a fixed pixel value it works perfectly, however if I use a variable for example(below) it doesnt work. I've also tried adding + 'px' but it just snaps the element into the width and doesnt animate it.

```
selfw = 250;
selfh = 250;

selfanimate.animate(
          {
            width: selfw,
            height: selfh,
          },
          500
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's just a matter of setting initial width and height to the element like I show in this demo with its own css rule.

Here I show the difference running the same animation on two different elements: one having the size initialized and the other isn't

```js
const w = '250px';
const h = '250px';

//initial size set on css rules
selfanimate.animate(
  {
    width: w,
    height: h,
  },
  500
);

//initial size not set on css rules
selfanimate_unset.animate(
  {
    width: w,
    height: h,
  },
  500
);
```

```css
#selfanimate{
  border: solid 1px red;  
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
}

#selfanimate_unset{
  border: solid 1px red;  
}
```

```html
<div id="selfanimate"></div>
<div id="selfanimate_unset"></div>
```